# PrestaShop $link -> getProductLink($product) gives incorrect URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm generating my product links in custom ajax powered module with `$link -> getProductLink($product)`

it's generating a URL like http://example.com/prestashop/2-blouse.html

which is throwing an error saying

> [Debug] This page has moved Please use the following URL instead:
>   http://example.com/prestashop/blouses/2-blouse.html

How do I avoid the same

Thanks

P.S: I'm using prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `false` in `config/defines.inc.php`.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is caused in the first place? 
(Setting `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `false` only disables the warning)

Comment: @Sathvik More info would be needed to find the source of the problem, but since it's only a warning and not an error, I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: This is not a solution but workaround. Why would the getProductLink() function return incorrect url? And how suposed I work with my debug mode off?

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences  > SEO & URLs

1. set disable friendly URLs and Save
2. set enable friendly URLs and Save

The .htaccess file will be refreshed and now it will not show you that message.

Comment: Message will not be showed cause it will be hidden, but the problem is not fixed. The Link::getProductLink() returns incorrect url