# Prestashop Link::getProductLink() returns wrong link (without category in it)

Tags: php, hyperlink, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.7

Link::getproductLink() returns incorrect url, after opening this url it's either redirection or error message when in dev mode.

Someone here ([PrestaShop $link -> getProductLink($product) gives incorrect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528902/prestashop-link-getproductlinkproduct-gives-incorrect-url)) had the same problem, people answered him to disable the DEV mode then the message ([Debug] This page has moved Please use the following URL instead:...)  is gone as the .htaccess redirects to the URL that is set in SEO options.

```
$product = new Product(123)
$link = new Link();
$product_link = $link -> getProductLink($product, null, null, null, 2);
$product_link returns: http://my.domain/de/123-product-name
```

While it should be: http://my.domain/de/category-name/123-product-name

Comment: Is your product only linked to the category wanted ? As your 3rd parameter is ``null`` the function should go itself search which category to use in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Look in the tab Set up shop -> Traffic and SEO -> block "URL format" you can choose the format of the product url

Regards

Comment: This is exactly my problem, the getProductLink() returns something different than set in SEO url option.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$product = new Product(123)
$link = new Link();
$product_link = $link->getProductLink(
    $product,
    $product->link_rewrite[2],
    Category::getLinkRewrite($product->id_category_default, 2),
    null, 
    2
);
```